# createChannel in GraphAPI sometimes results in not creating the corresponding Sharepoint/OneDrive folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Currently the creation of a channel through the Graph API frequently results in the relative, corresponding Sharepoint folder not being created.

When using the Graph API to create a channel the response indicates creating the channel was a success, but when going to the files tab it shows:

> "Your files can’t be found, working on it to restore them."

After having clicked on the files tab in the Teams UI, the folder is created eventually (after a couple of minutes).

But because automated processes depend on the channel folder, we don’t want to ask the user to manually open the team before the other processes can continue.

So: Team created: Ok -> Channel created: Ok-ish (But missing the linked folder) -> One-drive/share point folder, with the name of the channel: Not created

Sometimes the folder is created properly, but lately more often it is not created (Not even after 3-4 days of waiting) until the user opens the files tab in the Teams client.

This behaviour is new since it worked flawlessly until a week ago. Is there a known workaround for this?

We're following the default documentation for creating a channel via Graph API as described in the [Microsoft Graph Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Best regards,
Dominic

Comment: @dley- Could you please share request/response for which SharePoint folder is not created?

Comment: Request:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/channels
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "Test Channel",
  "description": "Description"
}

Comment: Response: {
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#teams('x34xxx68-6xxa-x67x-x9xc-f7xx10xxexx0')/channels/$entity",
  "id": "19:1x56xx4bxx70xx69xx2cxx76e94397db@thread.tacv2",
  "displayName": "Test Channel",
  "description": "Description",
  "email": "",
  "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3x1xxxx4b99704d69862c7d7xxxx397db%40thread.tacv2/Test+Channel?groupId=x34xxx68-6xxa-x67x-x9xc-f7xx10xxexx0&tenantId=7xxxfex4-5xx2-4xxc-axxf-6x3exxf9xx8x"
}

Comment: Any workaround you could apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design or rather limitation of SPO provisioning is async as in create team succeeds without waiting for SPO site provisioning completes. In those scenarios when channel get provisioned before SPO that get created without files folder. The recovery mechanism is accessing files tab in the channel.

Currently there isn't any solution to check if provisioning is completed. However, there is a feature ask to provide an API to provision similar to what happens on the client (clicking on Files tab). We do not have any ETA on this.

Comment: Is it possible to create the folder in another API request when it does not exist yet or will this have any bad impact on the provisioning proces which is not completed yet?